# c++ Finding closest four of a set of points

Tags: c++, k-means, nearest-neighbor

I have a set of points, each with an x and y coordinates. I would like to find the 4 of these points that are closest to together (if plotted all the points would be at different locations, but 4 of these points are always closer to each other, and I want to be able to identify which of the points these four are programmatically ). How do I go about doing this? I'm told it has to do with k-means or nearest-neighbors, but from my search results so far, I don't see how I could get it to work for my case since I'm finding the proximity of the points relative to each other and not to some fixed point. Any suggestions as to what topic/algorithm to look into, or code snippets will be much appreciated.

I thought an image of the exact problem might help. So these 8 points are contained in a vector, and I'd like to be able to identify which four are the ones clustered on the right.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "closest to each other"? Sum of distances between each pair of points in the set of four?

Comment: Is 4,7 really fixed? In this case, there would be only 35 possible sets of points, checking those brute force is absolutely feasible. It is only for higher `n` that it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: @Cameron - if you visualized the points in a window, you'd notice the point density is greater at a region that contains the four points and the remaining points in the set are always far from this dense area.

Comment: @AlexanderGessler - 7 isn't fixed, but four of the set are always closer together when visualized

Comment: You're probably going to want to look into computational topology and data visualization. One thing I vaguely remember being related to this is the problem of finding Betti numbers in graphs where two points are adjacent if they're less than a certain distance apart.

Comment: Possibly related: [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Related: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis` . You'll have to pick an algorithm and then implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force method would be to select every possible selection of four points (every permutation) and calculate e.g.:
1) the area enclosed by the points,
2) the perimeter of the convex hull of the points,
3) ...
and you'll find your four points by getting the minimum of the values calculated by 1), 2) or 3).

Comment: The area might be a bad idea, then 4 colinear points would have a distance of 0 no matter how far apart they are.

Comment: Minimum radius of a circle that contains or encloses all 4 points, is another possible measure

Comment: @MattMcNabb -  Turns out this problem is way harder to solve than I imagined. From what you said, I think I can use opencv's minenclosingcircle() to draw circles of a fixed radius (I know the ) with each of the 8 points as the center of one circle. And for the 4 of interest, because they are closer together, each of their circles will contain the other three points, but the other unwanted 4 points will always be alone in their circles. How does that sound?

Comment: You don't have to have one point as the centre (that is probably suboptimal). In fact if you take the convex hull of each 4 points as Martin suggested and then consider the longer of its two diagonals as the measure, I think that might be equivalent to my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Build a Delaunay Triangulation graph in nlog(n) complexity, there will be less than 2n edges to go over in order to find the four shortest ones.
you could try [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/).
You'd want to go over the edges like this: choose an edge, go three times to the shortest connected edge, and sum the edge lengths. save the vertices and the length sum of the minimal edge sum encountered thus far, and exhaust all the possible shortest neighbouring length combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mr.WorshipMe. It sounds like something that could work. I'm looking into the algorithm and poly2tri now and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Stralo Good luck, if this solves your problem, mark it as such :)